# Error: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: macos, git, ssh, osx-lion

Following [this](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) post to fix the following error:

```
>> ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Through the post made sure that I have a key and SSH is using it. I have even verified that the public key is attached to my github account. Not sure of the -1 in the last 3 lines? Saw all the related posts but no help.

```
 debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was doing `ssh -T git@github.com`. I had to do `ssh -T git@github.company's-github-account-name.com`. All set now.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem, it seems, is that the public key isn't actually correctly attached to your github account. Can you confirm that the output of

```
ssh-keygen -y -f /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

is exactly the same as what you put in Github, and that if you do

```
ssh-keygen -y -f /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa > tmp
ssh-keygen -l -f tmp
```

..that the fingerprint shown matches exactly one of the fingerprints shown at https://github.com/settings/ssh ?

---

**Edit**: you confirmed. It looks like you've done everything right, then. I can't think of much more that could be going wrong. I suppose you might be getting the wrong remote host (the IP is right, but a malicious person or a misbehaving corporate firewall could still be sending the packets to the wrong place). You can check this by seeing what fingerprint you've stored in your known_hosts file:

```
ssh-keygen -F github.com > tmp
ssh-keygen -l -f tmp
```

The output should start with:

```
2048 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
```

If it does, then I suppose it might be a problem on the github side after all. Maybe they have some sort of delay in between receiving your public key and propagating it to the main ssh server. You probably ought to try the "contact a human" link at the bottom of the page you cited.

Comment: Its exactly the same. Fingerprints also match.

Comment: Ya the output is exact same. I did post this SO post link to it. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Extensive troubleshooting of this GIT issue “Git – Permission denied (publickey)” can be done with the below command:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

1. Navigate to .ssh directory inside your home directory

   ```
   cd ~/.ssh
   ```
2. Generate the public/private rsa key pair

   ```
   ssh-keygen
   ```
3. Copy the SSH key to the clipboard using the below command

   ```
   cat id_rsa.pub | clip
   ```
4. Navigate to your GIT repository in https://github.com/
5. Go to Account Settings –> SSH Keys
6. Click on Add SSH key and store the key

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer posted by @Ava. Using `ssh -T git@github."company's_github_account".com` It worked for me. Many times, we do not realize that a simple fix exists for seemingly complex problems.